# Access Output PDF with Script Embeded VBA JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ms-access, pdf, vba

Being a non-traditional programmer, I tend to look at things in a different perspective. This happens to be one of those times. I have a `accdb` that currently runs and outputs `PDF` files every 2 minutes. The new `PDF`'s overwrite the old ones **except** when someone has one of the files open. In that case it skips the open file, the reattempts 2 minutes later. The issue I am running into is that some of the users who open these `PDF`'s, minimize them and forget about them, in some cases, not allowing the file to be updated for days, and even weeks. What I want to do is to embed a work action to close the file after several hours of being open. I found how to do so [enter link description here](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/Set-timer-to-auto-close-the-PDF-q41807.aspx) I have tested it, and it works. The problem I have is the I need somehow via `VBA`, embed that action into the `PDF` when it is created. The code I use to create it is:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "H&B Stock Research", acFormatPDF, strPathAndFile, False
```

All the sites I have researched show you how to accomplish adding the script/action though the Acrobat GUI. But I want to try to progmattically insert it via `VBA` in Access. The reason for this is that this file gets produced every 2 minutes, and there are approximately 50 copies that are updated.

Comment: Or, would there be a known method using VBScript to inject the properties post VBA output?

Comment: you may be able to achieve that if you have 2 folder location, one for your access output folder and one for user to view. Output the pdf into the "main folder" and then copy the newest copy to the user folder every 2 mins (remember to close if any pdf are open in that folder). Downside is... you have to copy and paste using VBA code from folder to folder

Comment: @raymondSee I should have clarified. I already have a setup like that. I have a `Batch` file that identify's the day and time, and if it is in the correct range, it executes a `accbd` file. The `dB` exports the `PDF` which the `Batch` file then executes a `VBS` script with copies, renames and moves the files. I am looking to see how I can automatically alter the `PDF`'s so that they close after a certain amount of time after they are opened.

Comment: I thing you can use the Acrobat API of the current version of your installed Acrobat. This can be done adding a reference in your VBA project to the Acrobat API.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the operational code in one place for better overview. Having said that, I would extend your current VBA function to check whether the file is open and if open for longer than 2 hours and a new version is available to copy. Close the opened file and copy the newest version.

This way you will have full control of copying the newest version and can manage your code all in one place.

I assume you already have the function to check whether the PDF is open.
adding this code will help you to terminate the opened file.

```
  Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
     Alias "FindWindowA" _
     (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
     ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

  Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" _
     Alias "PostMessageA" _
     (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
     ByVal wMsg As Long, _
     ByVal wParam As Long, _
     ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

  'Constants that are used by the API
  Const WM_CLOSE = &H10

  Dim mHwnd As Long
  mHwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, mFileName & " - Adobe Reader") ' application title 

  If IsWindow(mHwnd ) = 1 Then ' or just  If mHwnd Then
        'Send termination signal
        ' you can also capture the return value from postmessage to understand errors.
        PostMessage mHwnd , WM_CLOSE, 0&, 0&  ' 
        Debug.print "File was open but closed: " & mFileName
  End If
.. continue with your copy function
```

see this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/176391

Comment: Interesting. Would there be a way to nest this into my VBS script that copies and names? Or would this only be valid in the dB's VBA?